# scale div content to fit a fixed size

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two div's in my page with the following style.

```css
#currentExpr {
  visibility: hidden;
  height: 1px;
  width: 1px;
}

#currentExprFront {
  height: 3.5cm;
  font-size: 500%;
}
```

```html
<div id="currentExpr">\( \)</div>
<div id="currentExprFront"></div>
```

As you see, the first one is hidden. On it, some dynamic processes (JavaScript, call of external server, ...) are done until the div content (a long math ml expression) is obtained and updated.It is done on this hidden div to skip a lot of flicks, fast changes, ... until final content is obtained.

When final content is obtained, `currentExpr` content is copied to the visible div `currentExprFront` using the JavaScript statement:

```
currentExprFront.innerHTML = currentExpr.innerHTML;
```

Problem: I need to scale the content/div `currentExprFront` to fit the expected size (`3.5cm`). Sometimes, the content is bigger than this maximum. A possibility could be, by example, adjusting the font-size percentage.

Any hint? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Generate your content into a new element (like a span) and then query the size after it renders. In that split second compare the content size to the parent div size and adjust until the new element is smaller or close to the desired size

Comment: @Doug: thanks for your help. The initial element you say can be the "currentExpr" one, no problem to change it into a span. About second part, could you detail it a few more, in an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @Doug answer, the implemented solution has been replace the statement:

```
currentExprFront.innerHTML = currentExpr.innerHTML;
```

with the statements:

```
const k = 1.25;
const lk = Math.log(k);

function scaleAndCopy( d, o ) {
  /* width and height ratios */
  var h = d.offsetHeight/o.offsetHeight; 
  var v = d.offsetWidth/o.offsetWidth; 

  /* adjust to 1.25^n */ 
  h = Math.pow(1.25,Math.floor(Math.log(h)/lk)); 
  v = Math.pow(1.25,Math.floor(Math.log(v)/lk));

  /* set font size ratio and copy */
  var r = 100*Math.min(h,v); 
  d.style.fontSize = `${r}%`; 
  d.innerHTML = o.innerHTML
}

scale( currentExprFront, currentExpr );
```

this solution allows a single-step adjustment and keeps the fontSize stable to minor changes in the content, because the possible font size values are not continuous but 100%*1.25^n: ..., 80%, 100%, 125%, 156%, ... .

Answer (score 3):

This is a demo of what I tried to explain in the comments -- JavaScript can move very quick, so quick that the user's eye will not notice changes (or the browser may not bother to completely render).  So, using this speed advantage...

- Wrap the content into a container (in this case, a `span`).
- Populate the target `div` with the content that you're outputting.
- Measure the height of the `span` vs. the height of the `div`
- Increment the font-size based on whether the content is too large or too small.

```js
const target = document.getElementById('target');

const longText = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus ornare orci non tristique facilisis. Sed erat eros, dapibus sed arcu lobortis, consequat mollis odio. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Etiam efficitur metus enim, placerat varius felis fringilla vitae. Sed consectetur massa nec nulla ullamcorper tincidunt. Morbi eu orci hendrerit, egestas mi ac, consequat odio. Aenean id erat vitae sem mollis convallis quis in quam. Donec varius tempus ligula, in vulputate nisl pretium vel. Nullam ac arcu finibus, aliquam erat quis, lacinia metus. Aenean convallis magna et lectus mollis, eget scelerisque turpis dapibus. Donec sit amet erat mi. Sed tempus, tortor vel vehicula feugiat, elit purus fringilla tellus, eget molestie ex libero interdum mauris. Nam vehicula a justo et viverra. Aenean eget fringilla erat, id blandit sapien.';
const longTextBtn = document.getElementById('longText');
longTextBtn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{ addText( longText ); } );

const shortText = 'Lorem ipsum dolor.';
const shortTextBtn = document.getElementById('shortText');
shortTextBtn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{ addText( shortText ); } );

// addText() :: Responsible for creating the span element and 
//              assigning the text to the target div/container
function addText( phrase ){
  target.innerHTML = '';
  
  let targetSpan = document.createElement('span');
      targetSpan.id = 'tempID';
  let data = document.createTextNode( phrase );
  targetSpan.appendChild( data );
  target.appendChild( targetSpan );
  
  resizeText( targetSpan, target );
}

// resizeText() :: A recurssive function that will measure the size
//                 of the content vs. the size of the container and
//                 adjust the font-size accordingly.
// Needed improvements:
//  - Create a stop condition (to prevent an infinite loop)
//  - Create a condition to stop if/when the counter hits zero (0)
function resizeText( span, div ){

  let fontSizeTxt = span.style.fontSize || '10px';
      span.style.fontSize = fontSizeTxt;
  let fontSizeNum = parseInt( fontSizeTxt );

  // IF the text is SMALLER than the containing DIV

  if( div.offsetHeight > span.offsetHeight ){
    span.style.fontSize = `${fontSizeNum + 1}px`;
    // if the text is still too small, rerun
    if( div.offsetHeight > span.offsetHeight ){
      resizeText( span, div );
    }
  }
  
  // IF the text is LARGER than the containing DIV
  
  if( span.offsetHeight > div.offsetHeight ){
    span.style.fontSize = `${fontSizeNum - 1}px`;
    // if the text is still too large, rerun
    if( div.offsetHeight < span.offsetHeight ){
      resizeText( span, div );
    }
  }
  
}
```

```css
#target{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: Arial;
  border: solid 1px black;
}
  #target span{ display: block; }
```

```html
<div id="target"></div>
<br />
<button id="longText">Add Long Text</button>
<br />
<button id="shortText">Add Short Text</button>
```

Comment: Thanks again for your collaboration. There are not a property/method "scale" or "zoom"? In this way, it could be possible calculate the ratio current_size/target_size and, in one single step, adjust it.

Comment: That's definitely an interesting alternative approach :) It should be possible to do it in one stab ... I can try out a solution like that later on, but it gets you to the same logic path -- measure the containers, adjust accordingly.

Comment: The more I think about it, you're still going to need to do a series of guess and checks -- mostly because I don't think you can create an algorithm that will be good at predicting line breaks.  The only way it may work is if you find the height v width ratio of the parent container, constrain your content contain to match the same dimensions, and then scale by percentile -- but making the content container match the dimensional ratio brings you right back to guess and check