# font size relative to the size of parent

Tags: html, css, font-size

I have a container which can have different sizes depending how the user moved some elements on the screen. 
Inside this container there is an image and a text. The image fills out 80% of the height of the conainer and the text should fill out the other 20%. 
While the `height: 80%` works fine for the image `font-size: 20%` doesn't work for the text. I can't use vm or vh since the size has nothing to do with the screen size.

Comment: This might be a good reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50160006/scale-div-content-to-fit-a-fixed-size/50161166#50161166

Answer (score 0):

I found this link that should be helpful: [LINK](https://codepen.io/aknip/pen/GpGevp)

```js
flexFont = function () {
    var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("flexFont");
    for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
        var relFontsize = divs[i].offsetWidth*0.05;
        divs[i].style.fontSize = relFontsize+'px';
    }
};

window.onload = function(event) {
    flexFont();
};
window.onresize = function(event) {
    flexFont();
};
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "San Francisco";
  font-weight: 200;
  src: url("//applesocial.s3.amazonaws.com/assets/styles/fonts/sanfrancisco/sanfranciscodisplay-thin-webfont.woff2");
}

body, html {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    font-family: "San Francisco";
    font-weight: 200
}
.flexFont {
    height:8em;
    width:75%;
    background-color:#eeeeee;
    padding:1%;
    margin: 10px;
}

.smaller {
    font-size: 0.7em;
    background-color:red;
    width: 10em;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexFont">
    <h2>This is FlexText:<br>Autoscaling by DIV width</h2>
    <div class='smaller'>... scaled by 0.7em</div>
</div>

<div class="flexFont">
    <p>Font size scales parallel to the container width.<br>Change window size to test.<p>
</div>
```

Without the use of VM/VH you would need to use a combination of javascript and CSS to achieve this. The code above should help in what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: He says: "I can't use vm or vh since the size has nothing to do with the screen size."

Comment: AH missed that last line.

Comment: Updated the answer without using vh/vw

Answer (score 0):

Using a percent for `font-size` adjusts the font based on the current font-size for the document (it doesn't adjust the font to take up a percentage of the container). Check out [CSS Font-Size: em vs px vs pt vs percent](https://kyleschaeffer.com/development/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/).

For example:

```
/* current font-size for the document */ 
html {
  font-size: 20px;
}

/* results in 4px font-size for this div */
div {
  font-size: 20%;
}
```